# Gradle cannot build lombok annotated class

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I had changed my project from maven to gradle. but I had error with this command

```
./gradlew build --scan
```

for project that has lombok in it.

I've tried all method from online an it is useless. The build.gradle file is in kotlin language

[image: Build Error Output]

Here is the build.gradle.kts

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */

plugins {
    java
    `maven-publish`
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.3.9.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.3.9.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.9.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.9.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:2.2.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.2.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:2.2.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:2.2.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:2.2.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.9.RELEASE")
}

group = "com.bank"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
description = "transaction"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
        from(components["java"])
    }
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>() {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've used the latest version instead of lombok 1.18.18

```
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22")
    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22")
```

Comment: Looks like you added `annotationProcessor` and other parts as well, not just upgrading the version

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me. that you have to apply a plugin to your build script, as it's said in the [lombok docs](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle)

Something like this:

```
plugins {
  ...
  id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.4.2"
}
```

Or you have to provide annotation processor dependency, but I think that the plugin suits better.

Comment: I've tried this one but doesn't work

Comment: do you have for kotlin version?